# Как добавить псевдокласс hover перед псевдоклассом before, соблюдая вложенность, в препроцессоре less?

Tags: css, less, layout

Недавно начал изучать Less и во время практики столкнулся с проблемой.

```
.navbar{
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;

    ul{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
  
        li{
            margin-left: 50px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;

            li::before{
                content: '';
                bottom: -20%;
                background: #fff;
                width: 0;
                height: 2px;
                position: absolute;

            &:hover{
                width: 100%;
                transition: .5s;
            }
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Результат компиляции:

```
.navbar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar ul li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar ul li li::before {
  content: '';
  bottom: -20%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
.navbar ul li li::before:hover {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Суть проблемы в том, что hover после компиляции стоит после before (плюс, создается второй li). Я пробовал перемещать блок с hover выше, но естественно это не помогло.

Есть ли возможность это исправить не выходя из вложенности?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поменять местами `&:hover` и `li::before` пробовали?

Comment: А как в таком случае будет применяться :hover к ::before?

Answer (score 0):

```html
.navbar{
    height: 70px;

    ul{
        display: flex;
  
        li{
            margin-left: 50px;

            li {
                &::before{
                    content: '';
                    width: 0;
                }
                &:hover::before {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В итоге мы получаем вот это: .navbar ul li li:hover::before.

Comment: а разве не это требовалось? Ваше `Суть проблемы в том, что hover после компиляции стоит после before` можно трактовать по-разному. Напишите тогда, как именно у вас выглядит после компиляции, и что именно вам нужно получить в результате. Я, к примеру, так и понял, что вам нужно задать стиль для псевдоэлемента `:before` у `li`, на который навели мышь.

Comment: Я подкорректировал вопрос.